# Sum every second row only if cell below isn't empty?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write an excel formula to sum every second row in given column but only if the cell below/above is not empty.

My excel table is as follows:

```
      A           B         C
1   Group1      First       3
2               Second      9
3   Group2      First       -
4               Second      8
5   Group3      First       4
6               Second      -
```

---

```
7   Sum         Firsts      <formula1 - should ignore Group3 because its Second cell is empty>   
8               Seconds     <formula2 - should ignore Group2 because its First cell is empty>
```

Comment: Are the cells empty or dashed?

Comment: @basic they are empty not dashed, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` function for firsts:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B9=$B$1:$B$7)*($C$1:$C$7)*(B10=$B$2:$B$8)*($C$2:$C$8<>""))
```

and for seconds:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B9=$B$1:$B$7)*($C$1:$C$7<>"")*(B10=$B$2:$B$8)*($C$2:$C$8))
```

[image]